# Trying to paginate against a given date in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to paginate against a given date, but for some reason the query gives me an empty result.Maybe it's because of the query, or because of the entity, or because of parsing ... I don't know what could be happening

**EnvioRemesa**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ENVIO_REMESA")
public class EnvioRemesa {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "envio_sequence", sequenceName = "envio_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "envio_sequence")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "FECHA_ENVIO")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonDateDeserializer.class)
    @JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
    private LocalDateTime fechaEnvio;
```

**Controller:**

```
@GetMapping("/findByDate")
    public List<EnvioRemesa> getFindEnviosByDate(@RequestParam String fecha,@RequestParam Integer numEnvios, @RequestParam Integer numPag) {
        return envioRemesaService.getEnviosPorFecha(fecha,numEnvios, numPag);
    }
```

**Service class , method given:**

```
public List<EnvioRemesa> getEnviosPorFecha(String fecha, Integer numEnvios, Integer numPag) {
        PageRequest pageReq = PageRequest.of(numPag, numEnvios);
        List<EnvioRemesa> envios = envioRepo.findAll();
    
        if (numEnvios > envios.size()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error , no existen tanto envios");
        }
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(fecha, formatter);

    
        return envioRepo.findAllPorFecha(dateTime,pageReq).getContent();
```

**Repository interface**

```
@Repository
public interface EnvioRemesaRepository extends JpaRepository<EnvioRemesa, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM EnvioRemesa e WHERE e.fechaEnvio=?1")
     Page<EnvioRemesa> findAllPorFecha(LocalDateTime fecha,Pageable pageable);
```

The link im using:

```
http://localhost:8080/CashLetterAPI/rest/envio/findByDate?fecha=2021-04-23 11:22:04&numEnvios=1&numPag=0
```

Does anyone know what could be happening?

**EDIT 2**
Tried this query , but it doesnt work too

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM EnvioRemesa e WHERE e.fechaEnvio BETWEEN ?1 and ?1")
```

Comment: @Deadpool i edited the question with EnvioRemesa code

Comment: @Deadpool in sql developer thje field is declared like a Timestamp (LocalDateTime in Java) , maybe the query is bad?